# Debian stretch won't boot. Only with nomodeset set in grub

Tags: debian, amd-graphics

Setting "nomodeset" in grub loader boots the sistem but my graphic is all messed up, resolution and dual monitor support. Can you please give advice on how to fix this? I really don't want to reinstall my sistem. Graphic drivers were installed from debian wiki https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo and were working fine for a month.

Windows is working fine on the sistem. It's dualboot.

Sistem is fully upgraded debian stretch.

It crashed before any upgrade and dist-upgrade. Dist-upgrade brought new kernel. Same problem.

This is my graphic card. XFX HD6870

Comment: Edit your question und show `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 ` and `lsmod | egrep -i 'radeon|fglrx` please.